# Accessing variables from IPython interactive namespace in a script

Tags: python, ipython

Is there an easy way to access variables in the IPython interactive namespace.  While implementing a project that has a slow load command, I would like to run a script to load the data into the interactive work space, then call a second script that uses the data, like is possible with MATLAB.

In this simple case, what I want to do is

```
In [20]: a=5

In [21]: run tst
```

where tst.py is just

```
print a
```

The idea is that I want to run the loading script once, then just work on tst.py.

Thanks!

Answer (score 26):

Try using the -i option on IPython's magic run command; it makes the script run using the current interactive namespace, e.g. with

load.py:

```
a = 5
```

tst.py:

```
print a
```

From IPython I get;

```
In [1]: from load import *

In [2]: run -i tst
5
```

Comment: Great! This is the way to avoid copy-pasting into ipython.

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy or smart way to do this. One way would be to have a `main` function in your test function and then pass in the `globals` from your environment to update the `globals` in the caller. For example:

tst.py

```
def main(borrowed_globals):
    globals().update(borrowed_globals)
    print a
```

And then in iPython:

```
In [1]: a = 5

In [2]: import tst

In [3]: tst.main(globals())
5
```