# Run script in interactive namespace from within Canopy

Tags: python, enthought, canopy

From within the Canopy editor, how do I run a python script within the current interactive namespace?

Specifically, I have a large model object that takes a long time to load.  I would like to instantiate the model in the interactive shell and then be able to run scripts that operate on the existing model.  If I select the text in my script and click the "Run the selected text" button, everything works fine.  Alternatively, if I type "run -i script.py" as suggested in this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10622268/accessing-variables-from-ipython-interactive-namespace-in-a-script) it also works fine.  However, if I click the "Run the current file" button, the script appears to run in a clean namespace and cannot find any of the variables that already exist in the interactive shell.

This is the specific code that I am trying to use to only load the model on the first pass through the script.

```
# Only instantiating the model object if it does not already exist
if 'model' not in locals():
    model = TreeModel(filename)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click "Run the current file", then when it fails to run as desired, press the up arrow to recall the run command, insert the `-i`, and press Enter to re-run in ipython's interactive mode.

In theory, Canopy could be provided with this as yet another Run variant, but we want to avoid cluttering the UI with seldom-used options.

Comment: I noticed that there is an "Arguments" field in the "Run Configurations" dialogue box, but it appears to be for arguments that are passed to the script itself.  Would this be a logical place to add configurability for the run command itself?

Comment: It could not be implemented reasonably in that field, would need to be in another similar field.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguous "this".  Either an additional arguments field (or simply a checkbox if this is one of only a few common tweaks) in the "Run Configurations" dialogue box is what I was imagining.  Thanks for letting me know to stop searching for an integrated way of doing this and providing a workaround.

Comment: Got it. Submitted for feature request triage, in any case.